# How to clear have Arrayformula ignore empty strings?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet that is copying a SQL database through an integration. The script pushing data to Google sheet inserts new rows that have cells containing the "" value (empty string), rather than blank cells.
I have array formulas that add calculated columns in the Google sheets that won't expand over the cells containing an empty string value.

I am looking for either
(a) a way to make Google sheets ignore empty string and let arrayformula write over those cells,
(b) an apps script that finds and replace empty strings with blank cells. I am able to identify empty string cells using the regex ^s*$, but I don't know how to set the cell to blank (Clear and ClearContent set the value to an empty string).

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize that I cannot understand your question soon.

Comment: So you actually see `"" ` on the screen?

Comment: Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR($your-stuff))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.